# SwingConstants has same int value for Bottom and East?

Tags: java, swing, constants

While trying to get the horizontal alignment of a given JLabel, i noticed that `SwingConstants.TOP` has the same numeric int value as `SwingConstants.NORTH` (both are 1), but `SwingConstants.BOTTOM` has the same int value `SwingConstants.EAST` (both 3) instead of `SwingConstants.SOUTH` (5) !

```
    if (c instanceof JLabel) {
        JLabel tempLabel = (JLabel) c;
        //for meaning of values see javax.swing.SwingConstants.
        switch (tempLabel.getVerticalAlignment()) {
            case 0:
                output = VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.CENTER;
                break;
            case 1:
                output = VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.TOP;
                break;
            case 3: //Bottom but also east instead of south!
                output = VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.BOTTOM;
                break;
            default:
            //use default value setting
        }
    }
```

I wanted to make cases for all lower vertical alignments to (be it `BOTTOM, SOUTH, SOUTH_EAST, SOUTH_WEST`) to return `VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.BOTTOM` - but the int values of those constants do not have the expected consistency. How can i solve this best, and maybe also why are they defined in this strange way?

Comment: The problem is, the constants aren't used for the same thing.  As the documentation states, `BOTTOM` is used *"Box-orientation constant used to specify the bottom of a box"* where as `SOUTH` is (helpfully) described as *"Compass-direction south (down)."*.  The problem been, `BOTTOM` is intended to be used with `BoxLayout`, where as the other constraints are more "generalised".  My "gut" feeling is, `SwingConstants` was an inappropriate place to put the `BoxLayout` constraints, if they weren't going to be the same as the other values.  My "suggestion" is not to use them if you can avoid it

Comment: All right, thank you! I just saw in the javadoc of JLabel that `JLabel.getVerticalAlignment()` does have only a subset of possible `SwingConstants` output values. So i don't need to check for south-west, south-east (or south). Still a bit strange multi-use of direction values.

Comment: As I said, don't know why the "box layout" constraints are in there AND are not conforming to the same "conceptual" values, personally, I think it's a poor and lazy choice on the part of the developers, but I wasn't in the meeting which decided that course of action :P

Comment: Yeah :-D. Is kinda resolved since JLable restricts the possible values of SwingConstants. Should i delete the question?

Comment: Your choice, you could self answer it if you feel confident with the answer, it might help someone, who knows